# The strange "turning point" of $\arctan(x)/\arctan(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

After looking at an interesting graph:  $$y=\frac{\arctan(x)}{\arctan(\sqrt x)}$$

There seemed to be a turning point around $(3{,}88;1{,}198)$ (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/58wloddve3) <- A link to a graph of the equation

==========================================================

When $x < 0$, there are no real solutions as the square root of a negative number will result in a complex number. (And we can leave complex numbers for another day!)

When $x > 0$ and $x < 1$, The graph makes sense, as $\frac {a}{b}$ where $b > a$, and $b \ne 0$ will always return a number greater than $0$ and less than $1$. (The graph also passes through $(1;1)$, which is obvious because $\frac {1}{1} = 1$)

However, when $x > 1$, The graph acts slightly strange.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\arctan(x)}{\arctan(\sqrt x)} = 1$$

But why is there a turning point around $(3{,}88;1{,}198)$? I look forward to any explanations and answers, thank you!

King Regards

Joshua

Comment: I don't see any turning point and for $x\to\infty$ the limit is not $0$ but $1$. Can you explain how do you observe the supposed turning point ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Check here: [Graph of the equation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/58wloddve3) Look where x = 3.88 (about)

Comment: we have negative slope at infinity and positive slope at the origin and our function is smooth, so the derivative changes sign somewhere

Comment: @Joshua But what is strange?

Comment: @smcc Is there an explanation for the turning point? If it isn't strange, why does it do that?

Comment: Is it strange that $-x^2$ has a turning point at $0$?

Comment: @smcc Ok, so why does it do that? I can explain −x^2 having a turning point of 0 very easily: In the quadratic form, where a = -1, b = 0, c = 0... The x value of the turning point is (-b/2a) which is 0... and the y value is 0, therefore the TP of -x^2 is (0;0).... Your turn :)

Comment: You did not explain why you think it is strange that the function in your question has a turning point but do not think it is strange for $-x^2$ to have a turning point.

Comment: @smcc Ok, I see where you are coming from, with my use of the word, "Strange", I would just like to know why it is where it is... What is so special about  (3,88;1,198)?

Comment: Why is the turning point of $-x^2$ at zero? I am still struggling to see what your question is. The turning point is at about $x=3.88$ because that is where the derivative changes from being positive to negative. (Which is almost the same as saying the turning point is at $x=3.88$ because the turning point is at $x=3.88$!)

Comment: Nothing, just do the math correctly and solve the transcendental equation $y'(x)=0$ (numerically, asymptotically..etc.)

Comment: @smcc Thank you for your time and answers! Could you show how to do that possibly?

Comment: @tired Could you show how to do that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really asking, but I'll try to illustrate the point.

For convenience, we will use another function:

$$f(x)=\frac{\arctan {x^2}}{\arctan {x}}$$

If you set $t=x^2$ you will get back to your initial function.

The plot of this function for $x>0$ looks like this:

[image]

There is an obvious maximum (it's not usually called a turning point). To find where this maximum is, we have to solve:

$$f'(x)=0$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^4} \frac{1}{\arctan x}-\frac{1}{1+x^2} \frac{\arctan x^2}{(\arctan x)^2}$$

> $$\frac{2x(1+x^2)}{1+x^4} = \frac{\arctan x^2}{\arctan x}$$

Or we can rewrite this as:

> $$x=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ (1+x^4)\arctan x^2 }{(1+x^2) \arctan x }$$

This equation can only be solved numerically (see @tired 's comment).

See the numerical solution by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+x(1%2Bx%5E2)%2F(1%2Bx%5E4)%3DArcTan%5Bx%5E2%5D%2FArcTan%5Bx%5D).

$$x=\pm 1.96966420006958 \dots$$

> $$x^2=3.87957706103574 \dots$$

As you can see, this fits well with the value you provided.

---

One way to solve this equation is [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which I'm not going to show explicitly for this case, since it will be quite cumbersome.

Another possible way is to use the series for $\arctan$ which work for the arguments with absolute value $<1$:

$$\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+\frac{1}{5x^5}-\frac{1}{7x^7}+\dots \right)$$

Since we already have $x^4$ in our equation, it makes sense to leave all the terms with order $ \leq 4$, so we get an approximate equation:

$$\frac{2x(1+x^2)}{1+x^4} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3x^3}}$$

It's actually a six degree polynomial equation, which has only one real positive root $x=1.95161\dots$, which is close enough to the root of the original equation.

> Still, if you have a way to compute arctangents, I would recommend Newton's method.

Comment: Why is it not called a turning point, by the way?

Comment: @ZainPatel, I might be mistaken, but this would only be called a turning point if this curve represented a trajectory of some body in classical mechanics. If we are just talking about a function, then this is an extremum point (or a maximum point in this case). Again, I might be wrong

Comment: Ah, alright. The way I learnt what a turning point was that it's just a synonym for stationary point/extremum point/etc... anywho, not really a problem. Thanks for the reply. :-)

Comment: @ZainPatel, this is most likely correct.